# NSDateFormatter's dateFromString: returns nil in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios11

I've this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-03-01 13:42:17"];
```

For **< iOS 11**, expected date is found, but for **iOS 11** (Tested in iPhone with iOS 11.1) this is returning `nil`.

I didn't see any API changes for [dateFromString:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1409994-datefromstring?language=objc) in Apple's doc. What's wrong?

Comment: You didn't specify dateFormat first. So it'll take global Dateformat, which will not suite to your string. That's why it's nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically do not use the date / time styles to convert a date string. The styles represent different strings in different locales.

Use a fixed date format instead and set the locale to `en_US_POSIX`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2016-03-01 13:42:17"];
```

Comment: What if I need to set the locale to `[NSLocale currentLocale]`?

Comment: You can change the locale after the conversion. The most reliable locale for that date string is us Posix.

Answer (score 1):

@Vadian's answer worked for me in Swift as well! Thanks! :)

Here's the Swift version:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Date myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-03-01 13:42:17")
```